# Django TemplateSyntaxError at / 'staticfiles' is not a registered tag library. Must be one of: admin_list admin_modify admin_urls

Tags: python, django

I get the error when i run the code.
python3 manage.py runserver

TemplateSyntaxError at /
'staticfiles' is not a registered tag library. Must be one of:
admin_list
admin_modify
admin_urls
cache
i18n
l10n
log
propeller
static
tz
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 3.0
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:
'staticfiles' is not a registered tag library. Must be one of:
admin_list
admin_modify
admin_urls
cache
i18n
l10n
log
propeller
static
tz
Exception Location: /home/sggs/neerajbyte/Env-10-DeC/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py in find_library, line 1025
Python Executable:  /home/sggs/neerajbyte/Env-10-DeC/bin/python3

Answer (score 4):

Use `{% load static %}` instead of `{% load staticfiles %}`, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial06/#customize-your-app-s-look-and-feel

Answer (score 3):

`staticfiles` is now deprecated and you have to load it as `{% load static %}` instead of old way `{% load static from staticfiles %}`

Check notes on

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatetag-static
- Release notes for 3.0 version https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/deprecation/#deprecation-removed-in-3-0

  > The **staticfiles** and admin_static template tag libraries will be removed.